# Can't take string values from array

Tags: arrays, string, random, vbscript

```
Dim animals() As String = {"Dog", "Cat", "Goat", "Cow"}
Dim randomAnimal As Single = Int((UBound(Animals)+1)*Rnd())
```

Above code gives me an index value of an array instead of string.

Tried the below one but it doesn't work:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer= Int(randomAnimal)

Dim animals() As String = {"Dog", "Cat", "Goat", "Cow"}
Dim randomAnimal As Single = Int((UBound(Animals)+1)*Rnd())
```

Expected Result: Need to get any animal names in `randomanimal` from an array.

Comment: That code is not VBScript.

Comment: It's also not how accessing the elements of an array works in any language I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dim animals_array, animals_string, animal_random

randomize timer
animals_string = "Dog,Cat,Goat,Cow"
animals_array = split(animals_string, ",")
animal_random = animals_array(int((ubound(animals_array) + 1) * Rnd))
```